# Read sqlite3 db data into uint64_t

Tags: c, database, sqlite

I am very new to sqlite3 and I have question regarding insert and read uint64 data in sqlite3 DB. I am using Sqlite C interface.

While inserting data into sqlite3 DB, as I didn't see any function to bind uint64 data I have used sqlite3_bind_int64. So in DB data will store into signed int64.

I need to read same data into uint64. So query I have passed to sqlite3 to read is like :

"select ldtolu(length) from tblname"

Here "ldtolu" is an extension in sqlite which call int64_to_uint64, this should read data from DB which is signed int64 and I need to convert this into uint64. I wrote :

```
static void
int64_to_uint64(sqlite3_context *context, int argc, sqlite3_value **argv)
{
    u_int64_t value;
    value = (u_int64_t)sqlite3_value_int64(argv[0]);
    sqlite3_result_int64(context, (sqlite3_int64) (value));
}
```

Again here too I see only "sqlite3_result_int64" there is no function like "sqlite3_result_uint64".

Can anyone please help me how to bind uint64 and read same data or how to write extension to read int64 and cast it to uint64.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no *unsigned* 64-bit type among [SQLite's data types](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#storage_classes_and_datatypes).

To handle values larger than 9223372036854775807, you have to use floating-point numbers (which are not accurate enough to be able to repesent all integers) or strings.